# Setting `proxy-request-buffering off` leads to removing original `Content-length` header

Tags: kubernetes, nginx

I noticed that Nginx ingress caches big requests and I found that such behaviour can be switched off by `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-request-buffering: "off"` that in terms of Nginx is equal to `proxy-request-buffering off`

After that I started receiving no `Content-Length` header on my server side although it is sent on the client side

Is it expected behaviour? Can I receive the original `Content-Length`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is normal behavior. For more information you can check this [link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html) scroll down and look for syntax: proxy_buffering on | off.

There is also another explanation on this [link](https://www.nginx.com/blog/avoiding-top-10-nginx-configuration-mistakes/#proxy_buffering-off) wherein it mentioned to avoid this kind of configuration.

Comment: The articles are about `proxy_buffering` that related to proxy responses server->nginx. My question is about `proxy_request_buffering` that related to proxy requests client->nginx. I guess that disadvantages quite the same as described in the last article. But I didn't find any info or relation to the main question - why `Content-Length` is missed? I don't see any barriers to keep provided `Content-Length`